# how to rotate a 3d model rendered with ARCORE SceneView

Tags: android, kotlin, arcore

how to rotate a 3d model rendered with ARCORE SceneView  i have used Sceneview

private lateinit var scene: Scene
    private lateinit var node: Node

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.act_main)

    scene = sceneView.scene
    render(Uri.parse("coffee_cup.sfb"))
}

private fun render(uri: Uri) {
    ModelRenderable.builder()
        .setSource(this, uri)
        .build()
        .thenAccept {
            addNode(it)
        }
        .exceptionally {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return@exceptionally null
        }

}

private fun addNode(model: ModelRenderable?) {
    model?.let {
        node = Node().apply {
            setParent(scene)
            localPosition = Vector3(0f, -2f, -7f)
            localScale = Vector3(3f, 3f, 3f)
            renderable = it
        }

        scene.addChild(node)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the code block of Node().apply, add the following:

```
localRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(-1f, 0, 0), 90f));
```

Modify the (X,Y,Z) values according to how you want the object rotated. The coordinates I provided will make the object face the camera.